# Probability of inequality between random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

In order to prove a theorem in my research, I would like to use a lemma on basic probability theory, but I don't know if it is correct.

For three random variables $X,Y$, and $Z$ not necessarily independent, does the equality
$$ P(X \leq Y \leq Z) = P(X \leq Y)P(Y \leq Z)$$ hold?

$P(\cdot)$ is the probability operator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would generally not be true even if they were independent.

For example if $X,Y,Z$ were identically and independently continuously distributed then

they can come in any order with equal probability so $ P(X \leq Y \leq Z) = \frac16$

but similarly  $P(X \leq Y)P(Y \leq Z) = \frac12 \times \frac12 = \frac14$.

Comment: A lesson here is that even if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent, the events "$X\leq Y$" and "$Y\leq Z$" are not.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X=Z$, and $Y$ such that $P(X \le Y) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=Y)=0$, then in order for the equality to hold  we must have
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& P(X=Y) \\
&=&P(X \le Y \le Z) \\
&=& P(X \le Y) P(Y \le X)\\
&=& P(X \le Y) \left( 1-  P(X<Y) \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{4}
\end{eqnarray}
So the equality does not hold in general.

And that suchs $X$ and $Y$ exists, take $X=0$ and $Y$ the toss of a fair coin, where tails gets the value $1$ and heads the value $-3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is a little typo in the line $P(X \leq Y) (1 -P(Y<X))$.